# How to pass information from javascript to express to use it as a default value?

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs, data-transfer

So basically im using express, mongodb for the database, and ejs. I'm creating a form which can be submited to add a new article for a blog. If the form is missing information, the website is supposed to redirect back to the page whilst keeping the information in the boxes where they were. I've tried doing this however an error appears : "article is not defined" as if the data wasnt being sent to the page. So does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Here is my article.js file which is used to create new articles :

```
const express = require('express');
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const router =  express.Router();

module.exports = router

router.get('/new', (req, res) => {
  res.render('articles/new')
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {

});

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    markdown: req.body.markdown
  });
  try {
    article = await article.save()
    res.redirect(`/articles/${article.id}`);
  } catch (e) {
    res.render('articles/new', { article: article })
  }
});
```

Here is my new.ejs file which is used to display the form to create the article :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mb-4">New Article</h1>

    <form action="/articles" method="POST">
      <%- include('_form_fields') %>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my _form_fields.ejs file which is used as a template for the form :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input required value="<%= article.title %>" type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"><%= article.description %></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="markdown">Markdown</label>
  <textarea required name="markdown" id="markdown" class="form-control"><%= article.markdown %></textarea>
</div>

<a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

For a bit more context information, the error happened after I added: value="<%= article.title %>" to the _form_fields.ejs file.
I can help explain and send additional code snippets if needed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not really part of your question, but in this route `router.post('/', ...)`, you have no validation at all of any of the fields in `req.body` that you're using.  That could easily allow the user to create an empty article unless validation is happening somewhere else that you don't show.

Comment: You are POST-ing to `/article` but you haven't shown us the route to handle this. Instead you've given us the route for `/`. Either your `router.post('/',...` is wrong or your `<form action="/articles" ...` is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One coding error I see is that you do this:

```js
const article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    markdown: req.body.markdown
});
```

And, then later in the same function, you do this:

```js
article = await article.save()
```

But, you can't reassign to `article` because it is `const`.  That will throw an exception every time and then go to your `catch` block.

I'm not sure you really even need to reassign `article` at all, but if you do, then change:

```js
const article = new Article(...);
```

to this:

```js
let article = new Article(...);
```

FYI, errors like this are why you should always `console.log(err)` in a `catch` block so you can see exactly what error was thrown as it can sometimes be something you aren't expecting and don't think about  when debugging.

Comment: I've tried but when I switch to the articles/new page i still get the error message at the bottom of the page as if it didnt know what "article" was, as if I hadnt created the "variable". Any other ideas?